# Clear storyboard from memory

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am switching between two storyboards by a button press.

In ViewController.swift I switch to the new storyboard like this:

```
@IBAction func btnSwitchStoryboard(sender: AnyObject) {
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main2", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main2")

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

In Main2.swift I switch back to the other storyboard like:

```
@IBAction func btnSwitchStoryboard(sender: AnyObject) {
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main")

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I saw that the memory (+ 4 MB) is increasing by switching between the two storyboards. 
Is there a way to clear the memory of the previous storyboard or will iOS clear it by its own?

Comment: Test memory only on the device and only using a release build. Any other result is misleading.

Comment: Are you ever dismissing these view controllers? Just presenting them on top of each other over and over again is going to leave all the previous instances in memory

Comment: @dan where should I dismiss the previous view controller?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what you're doing but you could have Main2 dismiss itself instead of presenting a new instance of your first vc

Comment: would it be correct to `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` before `self.presentViewController`???

Comment: No, inside the second func only put `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`, then it should work